# Как задать функцию в обработчик событий на js без ее вызова

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая написана перед обработчиком событий. Когда задаю функцию в обработчик событий он ее вызывает без события. Как это исправить? Пробовал e.preventDefault(); и passive:true - не помогает

```
let act = () => {...};
card.addEventListener("click", act())
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Нельзя вызвать что то без соответствующего события

Comment: Убрать скобки у act

Comment: `const act = (e) => {}; card.addEventListener("click", act);`

Answer (score 1):

Убрать скобки у act

```
let act = () => {...};
card.addEventListener("click", act)
```

Comment: Попробуйте в функцию act передать параметры.

Comment: @Andrei, нафига?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вопрос первоначально был задан у функции были параметры. Зачем, спросите у автора фу-ции.

Comment: @Andrei, даже если там есть параметр, он всё равно сам передастся при этом коде.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мой вариант более универсален, вдруг кому-то когда-то придется передать какие-то параметры. Тогда как?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вот так:

```
let act = (e) => {};
card.addEventListener("click", (e) => act(e))
```

Comment: Браузер выдает ошибку. Надо было просто убрать скобки у act

Comment: Ну Семен Семеныч! `let act = () => {};` -> `let act = (e) => { e.target... };`

Comment: @АлексейКартышев act тоже должен принимать аргумент в фукнцию

Comment: @АлексейКартышев, не может тут быть ошибки, тем более, в браузере.